# How to install Ubuntu on a laptop that has fedora

Tags: 12.04, installation

I simply want to get rid of the latest version of Fedora that is currently on my laptop and install Ubuntu instead. Can someone please tell me how? I followed the "get ubuntu" links on the site but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to completely get rid of fedora and install , simply download ubuntu 12.04 from ubuntu website . Once you have downloaded you can burn it in a cd . or you can use a tool called "unetbootin" (google to download unetbootin) once you have the tool make it as a USB bootable and then boot from CD or USB and just follow the on screen instructions . If you have already tried it, tell us at which point you get error . please give more details to help youout